# Problem calculating kmeans and simple structure index within the terra package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, terra

### Working within terra to make unsupervised classification

I have been working with the terra pacakge for a while, and now I am trying to see whether I can make some tasks that I use to do in raster where I had to transfom the rasters into data frames before making a function, a usual task where I use to do that was optimum classes for spatial rasters, what I use to do is something like this:

First I load the packages and transform the stack to a dataframe

```r
library(terra)
library(geodata)
library(vegan)
library(dplyr)

# download climatic variables from terra
Clim <- geodata::worldclim_country(country = "denmark", var = "bio", path = getwd())


# Transform to data frame, keeping the cells to translate back to raster
ClimDF <- terra::as.data.frame(Clim, cells = T)
```

Then I used the cascadeKM function from the vegan package where I state that I want to test clustering from 2 to 5 groups. This will make these clusters and calculate some index, either calinski or Simple Structure Index and with that see which is the optimum clustering

```r
## Use cascade km to find several  kmeans plus index
Clust <- vegan::cascadeKM(data = ClimDF[,-1], inf.gr = 2, sup.gr = 5)

## Get the maximum Calinski to see what is the optimum clustering
OptimumClust <- Clust$results |> 
  t() |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  dplyr::filter(calinski == max(calinski)) |> 
  rownames()
```

And then I get the values back to the template

```r
Template <- Clim[[1]]

values(Template) <- NA

Template[ClimDF$cell] <- Clust$partition[,OptimumClust]

plot(Template, colNA = "black")
```

[image]

Now I would like to bypass the whole transformation to a data.frame, so I tried first to just do the kmeans, to then see if I could actually calculate either calinski or SSI, but even at that point I got stuck, I was following this [tutorial](https://rspatial.org/terra/rs/4-unsupclassification.html), however this is not working

### First try

I tried to replicate the abovementioned tuorial:

```r
set.seed(99)
# We want to create 10 clusters, allow 500 iterations, start with 5 random sets using "Lloyd" method
kmncluster <- kmeans(na.omit(Clim), centers = 5, iter.max = 500, nstart = 5)
```

However, I get this error

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

I am not sure why I get this error at first, wouldnt the na.omit take out the NA values? and I checked that there are no Inf or -Inf. My dream scenario would be to get to do all that is done in the cascadeKM with spatVect and not having to go to data.frame and back, but if I can really even do a kmeans I cant even start

Answer (score 2):

I assume that example in the tutorial fails because you have NAs in your data. Here is an expanded version (with simpler input data) that accounts for NAs.
Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
s[1,] <- NA
```

k-means

```
v <- na.omit(values(s))
set.seed(99)
kmn <- kmeans(v, centers=5, iter.max = 500, nstart = 5, algorithm="Lloyd")

kr <- rast(s, nlyr=1)
i <- attr(v, "na.action")
j <- (1:ncell(s))[-i]
kr[j] <- kmn$cluster

plot(kr)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @RobertHjmans, so,it seems that you cant do the kmeans directly on the SpatRast, my bad, I had seen the tutorial wrong. Do you thing there might be a way to do it compling a function in C++? I would be happy to try if you think it is feasible